# Nested object not mapping with server side model

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model

Am trying to send a nested object to my mvc controller through AJAX.
My Data set is kind of below.

```
   function GetValuesForSave() {

        var model = {
            Partycode: "x",
            DocDate: new Date(),
            DocNo: 1,
            SaleItems: {
                StockCode:'',
                Amount: 1,
                DiscPerc: 1,
                DiscAmount: 1,
                Qty: 1,
                Rate: 1,
                Description: '',
                Unit: ''
            }

        }

        return model;
    }
```

My Ajax call:

```
var datatosend=GetValuesForSave();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Sales/SaveSales/",

      data: datatosend,
      success: function() {
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("failure");
      }
    });
```

My model structure:

```
public class SalesViewModel
{
    public string Partycode { get; set; }
    public DateTime DocDate { get; set; }
    public int DocNo { get; set; }
    private SaleItem _saleItem;
    public SaleItem SaleItems { get; set; }
}

public class SaleItem
{
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public double Qty { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
    public double DiscPerc { get; set; }
    public double DiscAmount { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

My controller method:

```
public ActionResult SaveSales(SalesViewModel m)
{
    var data = sale;
    return View();
}
```

The issue am facing is am able to get the main model details from controller, but the nested object fields are null am i missing something.
Is i need to do anything with the GET SET of the nested property. I Tried sending the data as a JSON string still am getting the same result.
[image]

Please find the chrome console log

[image]

Comment: Your ajax call uses `datatosend` as data, but your data above is declared as `model`. Is this intentionally?

Comment: I didn't put my whole method code, the data is in the datasend variable. will edit the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: If there is a step in between the declaration of your data and the ajax call, have you checked if the data is correct before you send the request?

Comment: @TobiasTengler the name 'datatosend' is just a name of a local variable in JavaScript that holds the data object. What's really important to understand what's the issue is the JSON of the data object.

Comment: Please share the JSON of the data that you send to server. E.g., add console.log(datatosend) before $.ajax(...), or find it in the Network tab of browser dev tools

Comment: Updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently performing a GET request. Because of this jQuery's `ajax` method tries to interpret `data` as a query string, which is why you only get the "top-level" Key-Value-Pairs in your controller method.

In order for it to work, you'd need to modify your `ajax` call to this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", // perform POST request
  url: "/Sales/SaveSales/",
  data: JSON.stringify(datatosend), // serialize your data into JSON
  contentType: "application/json", // tell server to interpret data as JSOn
  success: function() {
    alert("success");
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("failure");
  }
});
```

In your controller you also have to specify that `m` should be taken from the POST request's body, by marking your endpoint as [`HttpPost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing-with-httpverb-attributes) and annotating your parameter with the [`FromBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) tag:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSales([FromBody] SalesViewModel m)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: HttpPost from web.HTTP or WEB.MVC?

Comment: Worked like a charm Thanks not only for the answer but also for the description and the links provided.

Comment: For anybody who is viewing this, I confused the model binder by accidentally including a root json node encapsulating all of my properties that were supposed to be binding to my model... keep an eye out for that.

Answer (score 1):

Specify your action verb to `HttpPost`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSales(SalesViewModel m)
{
     ...
}
```

and your API call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SaveSales/",
    type: "POST",
    ...
}
```

[image]